# How to persist Python class with member variables that are also Python classes having large `numpy` array variables (so `pickle` no longer efficient)?

Tags: python, json, numpy, persistence, pickle

The use case: Python class stores large numpy arrays (large, but small enough that working with them in-memory is a breeze) in a useful structure. Here's a cartoon of the situation:

**main class:** `Environment`; stores useful information pertinent to all balls

**"child" class:** `Ball`; stores information pertinent to this particular ball

`Environment` member variable: `balls_in_environment` (list of `Ball`s)

`Ball` member variable: `large_numpy_array` (NxN numpy array that is large, but still easy to work with in-memory)

I would like to preferably persist `Environment` as whole.

Some options:

- `pickle`: too slow, and it produces output that takes up a LOT of space on the hard drive
- database: too much work; I could store the important information in the class in a database (requires me to write functions to take info from the class, and put it into the DB) and later rebuild the class by creating a new instance, and refilling it with data from the DB (requires me to write functions to do the rebuilding)
- JSON: I am not very familiar with JSON, but Python has a standard library to deal with it, and [it is the recommended solution of this article](http://www.benfrederickson.com/dont-pickle-your-data/) -- I don't see how JSON would be more compact than `pickle` though; more importantly, doesn't deal nicely with `numpy`
- MessagePack: another recommended package by the same article mentioned above; however, I have never heard of it, and don't want to strike out into the unknown with what seems to be a standard problem
- `numpy.save` + something else: store the numpy arrays associated with each `Ball`, using `numpy.save` functionality, and store the non-numpy stuff separately somehow (tedious)?

What is the best option for my use case?

Comment: Quick check: if you're on Python 2, did you try `cPickle`? And did you set the protocol version?

Comment: [hdf5](http://www.h5py.org/) is probably your best bet. It's what pandas uses for quick IO of large datasets.

Comment: `np.save` resorts to pickle for variables (and elements of arrays) that it can't save as normal arrays.  `savez` saves multiple arrays, one per file, in a `zip` archive (compressed or not).

Comment: It should be relatively painless to use HDF5 to serialize arbitrary Python classes with numpy arrays as members (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18071075/1461210) for an example using dicts)

Comment: Another good option would be to use [`joblib.dump`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.dump.html#joblib.dump), which internally uses `np.save` for numpy arrays and `cPickle` for everything else.

Comment: @user2357112 I haven't tried `cPickle`; I'll look into it along with the protocol version options!

Comment: @AdamAcosta I don't see how that's my best since (and I might be misunderstanding, so please correct me) it's geared particularly towards storing VERY large numerical arrays, rather than Python objects such as classes? I don't have very large numerical arrays, and I prefer to work with the arrays in-memory.

Comment: @ali_m So, if a Python class has `numpy` arrays, does `joblib` handle the hassle of picking apart the `numpy` array for saving using `np.save`, and then re-integrating those member variables back in during load time?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, [`joblib.dump`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.dump.html#joblib.dump) might be a good option. It uses `np.save` to efficiently store numpy arrays, and `cPickle` for everything else:

```
import numpy as np
import cPickle
import joblib
import os


class SerializationTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)

st = SerializationTest()
fnames = ['cpickle.pkl', 'numpy_save.npy', 'joblib.pkl']

# using cPickle
with open(fnames[0], 'w') as f:
    cPickle.dump(st, f)

# using np.save
np.save(fnames[1], st)

# using joblib.dump (without compression)
joblib.dump(st, fnames[2])

# check file sizes
for fname in fnames:
    print('%15s: %8.2f KB' % (fname, os.stat(fname).st_size / 1E3))
#     cpickle.pkl: 23695.56 KB
#  numpy_save.npy:  8000.33 KB
#      joblib.pkl:     0.18 KB
```

One potential downside is that because `joblib.dump` uses `cPickle` to serialize Python objects, the resulting files are not portable from Python 2 to 3. For better portability you could look into using HDF5, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18071075/1461210).