# Storing Numpy or Pandas Data in Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to decide the best way to store my time series data in mongodb. Outside of mongo I'm working with them as numpy arrays or pandas DataFrames. I have seen a number of people (such as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367589/saving-numpy-array-in-mongodb)) recommend pickling it and storing the binary, but I was under the impression that pickle should never be used for long term storage. Is that only true for data structures that might have underlying code changes to their class structures? To put it another way, numpy arrays are probably stable so fine to pickle, but pandas DataFrames might go bad as pandas is still evolving?

UPDATE:

A friend pointed me to this, which seems to be a good start on exactly what I want:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html

Numpy has its own binary file format, which should be long term storage stable. Once I get it actually working I'll come back and post my code. If someone else has made this work already I'll happily accept your answer.

Comment: hard to say without seeing your data, but if it's just a simple time series, why not just a CSV file?

Comment: I'd like to minimize the processing of the data when it goes in and out. If I have a numpy array of 100,000 floats before hand, and I'd like to work with them as numpy arrays afterwords, it seems expensive to turn them into csv files for storage.

Comment: you got the answer, but for everyone else: if you think converting to CSV will be slow and painful, wait until you try to load it into mongodb

Answer (score 1):

We've built an open source library for storing numeric data (Pandas, numpy, etc.) in MongoDB:

https://github.com/manahl/arctic

Best of all, it's easy to use, pretty fast and supports data versioning, multiple data libraries and more.